# JavaFX8 triggering an event if the Node is shown on screen

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In JavaFX 8 I have few tabs in a tabbed pane, these tabs are added dynamically based on some logic. The tab's content is loaded from a FXML.

When a tab is active and visible one of the Node that is present in that tab has to be populated by starting a task. This task must stop if some other tab is chosen. i.e when the tab contents are visible I should start a task and if the tab is no longer visible I need to stop the task.

I have already tried attaching a changeListener to visibleProperty of one of the Node's in the tab, but this doesn't produce a changeEvent as expected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a listener to the `selectedItem` property of the `TabPane`'s selection model:

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel()
    .selectedItemProperty()
    .addListener((obs, oldTab, newTab) -> {
        // if oldTab == tab with your node, stop task
        // if newTab == tab with your node, start task
    });
```

Comment: The problem is, I wouldn't know in the code what will be the contents of a tab. i.e the tab contents are loaded dynamically based on certain conditions. For ex: I have 100 possible contents (not nodes, but 100 different FXML's) for the tabs that are defined and I may load 1 out of the 100. Ofcourse I can add extra logic to figure out whether the particular FXML is present, but my question is more generic and not specific to tabs, Is there a way that a node can be queried up on to see whether it is currently showing on screen? In this way I can use the controller of the FXML to start the task